Wedge Product and Differential Forms, example

Let $x=id_{\mathbb{R}^4}$, $\alpha=dx^1+x_2dx^2\in \Omega^1\mathbb{R}^4$, $\beta=\sin(x_2)dx^1\wedge dx^3+\cos(x_3)dx^2\wedge dx^4\in \Omega^2\mathbb{R}^4$, $h(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(x_1, x_2, x_3x_4, x_4)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{R}^4)$.
Determine (1)$\gamma=\alpha\wedge\beta$, (2)$h^*\gamma$.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me whether my results are correct before I continue with  the remaining calculations:
(1)$$\gamma=\alpha\wedge\beta=(dx^1+x_2dx^2) \wedge (\sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge dx^3+\cos(x_3)dx^2 \wedge dx^4)\\=dx^1 \wedge \sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge dx^3+x_2dx^2 \wedge \sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge dx^3+dx^1 \wedge \cos(x_3)dx^2 \wedge dx^4+x_2dx^2 \wedge\cos(x_3)dx^2 \wedge dx^4\\=\sin(x_2)(dx^1 \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^3)-x_2\sin(x_2)(dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3)+\cos(x_3)(dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4)+x_2\cos(x_3)(dx^2 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4)\\=\cos(x_3)dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4-x_2\sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3$$
(2)$$h^*\gamma=h^*(\cos(x_3)(dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4)-x_2\sin(x_2)(dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3))\\=h^*\cos(x_3)\wedge h^*dx^1 \wedge h^*dx^2 \wedge h^*dx^4-h^*(x_2\sin(x_2)) \wedge h^*dx^1 \wedge h^*dx^2 \wedge h^*dx^3\\=\cos(x_3x_4) \wedge h^*dx^1 \wedge h^*dx^2 \wedge h^*dx^4-x_2\sin(x_2) \wedge h^*dx^1 \wedge h^*dx^2 \wedge h^*dx^3\\=\cos(x_3x_4)dx^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4 - x_2\sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge  dx^2 \wedge  (x_4dx^3+x_3dx^4)\\=(\cos(x_3x_4)-x_2x_3\sin(x_2))dx^1 \wedge  dx^2 \wedge  dx^4-x_2x_4\sin(x_2)dx^1 \wedge  dx^2 \wedge  dx^3$$

Two suggestions. 1) Don't mix coordinates with lower indices and coordinates with upper indices. 2) Don't use the same letters for coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$ and coordinates on $\Bbb R^4$, although whoever gave you this exercise screwed up both these suggestions.  I suggest using $y^1,\dots,y^4$ on $\Bbb R^4$. Now $h$ gives each $y^i$ as a function of $x^1,\dots,x^3$. Oh, and pullback needs a ^ when you type it: h^* gives $h^*$.

P.S. You might want to check out my lectures on differential forms. See my profile to the link to the YouTube videos. (If you start with lecture 24, the very first on differential forms, be warned that the complete lecture 24 is at the very bottom of the list.)

Oh, my $\Bbb R^3$ should have been $\Bbb R^4$. The comments still stand.

@TedShifrin Thank you! I just copied the indices  used  in the exercise  but yes, it‘s quite confusing, you‘re right! I will also go and  check  out your lectures on the topic!

A few tips. (1) when you have $\alpha\wedge \beta$ you do not have to write out terms that carry identical differentials  because they will be zero. You need to keep only the terms that have $dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k$ with $i,j,k$ all different. (2) Calculation of pullback is just ordinary calculus. The only interesting one in your case is $h^*dy^3$ because that $y^3$ is $x^3x^4$ and not just $x^3,.$
